# how to save multiple column and display single column list view?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

Hey i am trying to use database using database helper i am able to write data as per toast but whenever i get record to list view the application stops working Please anybody can help .This is the code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class bills extends AppCompatActivity {
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
ListView mrecycleview;
private static final String TAG ="bills";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_bills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mrecycleview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mRecycleView);
    dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    // mlistview();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Editbills.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
   // mlistview();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bills, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 /* private void mlistview(){
    Log.d(TAG,"mlistview:Display data in listview");
    Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.getAllRecords();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(mCursor.getString(1));
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listData);
    mrecycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
}*/
}
```

this is the code for DbAdapter that i have used to save and read database and display it on a listview.

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
public static final String KEY_COURSE = "course";
// public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "billsdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bills";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR );";

private final Context context;    

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String title, String duedate, String course) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    initialValues.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String query ="SELECT * FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE;
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord()
{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String title, String duedate, String course) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    args.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

this is the logcat of the code i am getting please help

```
03-24 01:16:22.787 1096-1096/com.example.dhruv.bills E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.dhruv.bills, PID: 1096
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dhruv.bills/com.example.dhruv.bills.bills}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMbills1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMbills1
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMbills1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMbills1
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1393)
                                                                       at com.example.dhruv.bills.DBAdapter.getAllRecords(DBAdapter.java:98)
                                                                       at com.example.dhruv.bills.bills.mlistview(bills.java:68)
                                                                       at com.example.dhruv.bills.bills.onCreate(bills.java:42)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: please provide the log cat so that the errors are identified >

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi how to attach logcat now?

Comment: try to edit your question, you must see the gallery icon there while editing.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi attached now please check

Comment: Mind your **spaces**! `{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;`

Comment: @KlingKlang yeah it is working perfectly fine now. thanks for your help brother .

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497655/how-to-retrieve-multiple-data-when-clicked-on-listview can you please answer this question it would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted a space between the keyword `FROM` and the table **bills1**, that is the SQL has `FROMbills1` when it should be `FROM bills1` ***(see below re table name)***.

Looking at your code you have two methods that should be changed. Instead of :-

```
//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String query ="SELECT * FROM" + DATABASE_TABLE;
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord()
{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

you could have :-

```
//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String query ="SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE; //<<<< space added after FROM
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord()
{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM " + KEY_TITLE; //<<<< space added after FROM
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

- Note the 2nd method would fail as KEY_TITLE, which resolves to **title** is not a table.

I cannot see from the provided code how you have got the table name **bills1** as DATABASE_TABLE is defined as **bills**. Furthermore your code appears to only create a table named **assignments** as per :-

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR );";
```

I would suggest only using a single source for table and column names throughout your code. Doing so would largely eliminate the problems.

---

#### Additional

Having a closer look there are additional issues with the DBAdapter class, here's a re-written version that incorporates the single definition of table and column names and also fixes those issues (see the comments) :-

```
public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
    public static final String KEY_COURSE = "course";
    // public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "billsdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bills";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR );";

    // Replaces DATABASE_CREATE using the one source definition
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + // AUTOINCREMENT NOT REQD
                    KEY_TITLE + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_DUEDATE + " DATE ," +
                    KEY_COURSE + " VARCHAR " +
                    ")";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE); // NO need to encapsulate in try clause
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts"); //????????
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a record into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String title, String duedate, String course)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
        //return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
        // Replaces commented out line
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,
                initialValues
        );
    }

    //---deletes a particular record---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the records--- SEE FOLLOWING METHOD
    public Cursor getAllRecords()
    {SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String query ="SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return data;
    }

    //As per getAllRecords but using query convenience method
    public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
                DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
    }

    //---retrieves a particular record--- THIS WILL NOT WORK - NO SUCH TABLE
    public Cursor getRecord()
    {String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    // Retrieve a row (single) according to id
    public Cursor getRecordById(long id) {
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
                DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,
                KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,null,null
                );
    }


    //---updates a record---
    public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String title, String duedate, String course)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        args.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
        String whereclause = KEY_ROWID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)};
        // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
        //return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        // Replaces commented out line
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(DATABASE_TABLE,
                args,
                whereclause,
                whereargs
        ) > 0;
    }
}
```

The above code has been tested (at least inserting and retrieving data) using the following code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBAdapter mDBAdapter;
    Cursor mCsr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        addSomeData();

        mCsr = mDBAdapter.getAllAsCursor();
        while (mCsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("BILLDATA",
                    "Title="+mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE)) +
                            " Due Date=" + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DUEDATE)) +
                            " Course=" + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_COURSE))
            );
        }
        mCsr.close();
    }

    // Add some data (note will add 3 rows each time it is run)
    private void addSomeData() {
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill1","2018-10-02","English");
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill2","2018-09-03","Mathematics");
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill3","2018-11-04", "Geography");
    }
}
```

**Output to the Log** (after 3rd run) :-

```
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill1 Due Date=2018-10-02 Course=English
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill2 Due Date=2018-09-03 Course=Mathematics
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill3 Due Date=2018-11-04 Course=Geography
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill1 Due Date=2018-10-02 Course=English
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill2 Due Date=2018-09-03 Course=Mathematics
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill3 Due Date=2018-11-04 Course=Geography
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill1 Due Date=2018-10-02 Course=English
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill2 Due Date=2018-09-03 Course=Mathematics
03-23 21:34:10.164 1644-1644/so49457069bills.so49457069bills D/BILLDATA: Title=Bill3 Due Date=2018-11-04 Course=Geography
```

### NOTE

***I would strongly suggest that after making changes that you uninstall the App or clear the App's data before running the App. This will delete the database and which will then be recreated and then invoke the Database helper's `onCreate` method***

Comment: thanks brother it is working perfectly fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: @dhruvsachdeva that's good. Could you please tick the question as answered.

Comment: Done brother . 

Comment: please answer this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497655/how-to-retrieve-multiple-data-when-clicked-on-listview-and-update-data-to-the-re