# How to Retrieve Multiple data when clicked on listview?

Tags: java, android, sql, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want all edit text content that I have saved in SQL to be displayed on the edit bills activity when I click on the list item, but I am only able to retrieve the name and display it again in the intent. Rather than saving another data it should update the record with the new data if I save the existing record another time in the editbills_activity.
Here is my DBAdapter.java

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log; 
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "billsdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bills";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "name VARCHAR not null, amount VARCHAR, duedate date );";

// Replaces DATABASE_CREATE using the one source definition
private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + // AUTOINCREMENT NOT REQD
                KEY_NAME + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AMOUNT + " VARCHAR ," +
                KEY_DUEDATE + " DATE " +
                ")";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE); // NO need to encapsulate in try clause
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts"); //????????
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String name, String amount, String duedate)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    //return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
    // Replaces commented out line
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,
            initialValues
    );
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records--- SEE FOLLOWING METHOD
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query ="SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}


//As per getAllRecords but using query convenience method
public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,null,null,null,null,null
    );
}
public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +
            " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
//---retrieves a particular record--- THIS WILL NOT WORK - NO SUCH TABLE


/* public Cursor getRecord()
{String query1 ="SELECT * FROM" + KEY_TITLE;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query1,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}*/

// Retrieve a row (single) according to id
public Cursor getRecordById(long id) {
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            null,
            KEY_ROWID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null,null,null
    );
}


//---updates a record---


/* public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String amount, String duedate)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
    args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    String whereclause = KEY_ROWID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)};
    // Will return NULL POINTER EXCEPTION as db isn't set
    //return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    // Replaces commented out line
    return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(DATABASE_TABLE,
            args,
            whereclause,
            whereargs
    ) > 0;
}*/
}
```

Here is my Bills.java
(MainActivity)

**Problem:** Bills.java has the list view that shows the intent whenever the item in list view is clicked, but it does not put the amount and date or update the record. Instead it saves another record.

**Solution:** I want to retrieve it and display all (name ,amount,duedate) and instead of saving another record it should update it.

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class bills extends AppCompatActivity {
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
ListView mrecycleview;
private static final String TAG ="assignments";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bills);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mrecycleview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mRecycleView);
    dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    // mlistview();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Editbills.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mlistview();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bills, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


 private void mlistview(){
    Log.d(TAG,"mlistview:Display data in listview");
    Cursor mCursor = dbAdapter.getAllRecords();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(mCursor.getString(1));
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listData);
    mrecycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
  mrecycleview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
          Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);
          Cursor data = dbAdapter.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
          int itemID = -1;
          while(data.moveToNext()){
              itemID = data.getInt(0);
          }
          if(itemID > -1){
              Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
              Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(bills.this, Editbills.class);
              editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
              editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
              startActivity(editScreenIntent);

          }
          else{

          }
      }
  });


}
}
```

here is my editbills.java code

```
package com.example.dhruv.bills;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Editbills extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
private static final String Tag= "assignments";
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
private String selectedName;
private int selectedID;
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editbills);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editText.setText(selectedName);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("test", "adding");
            db.open();
            long id = db.insertRecord(editText.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString());
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(Editbills.this," Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bills.class);
            startActivity(q);

        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: in `editbills.java` you wanna update the row whose id is received from the `intent` ?

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi i want to update the column that i add on clicking the list view which uses the row id to set the text to the edit text that was saved earlier

Comment: so, you wanna update the item which is clicked on the listView?

Comment: and in your edit bills activity why aren't you calling the `updateRecord` method ?
you are instead calling the `insertRecord` method

Comment: rather than providing a solution for updating the column i want you to help me for retrieving all the values of the column or edit text when i click on the item in Listview. i amm only able to retreive 1 string that is name for which i have added code in bill.java @NiamatullahBakhshi

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi even if i call update record it shows me up with an error

Comment: you are not able to retrieve the data too?

Comment: yes that's the major problem i am facing i saw the other code from where i was able to retrieve one string but i am not able to retrieve all the columns @NiamatullahBakhshi

Comment: to get all the columns you need to add `*` in your SELECT query.
`getItemId` just returns `KEY_ROWID`.

Comment: This now should return all the columns of the row you want.

`public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +
            " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}`

Comment: can you help me with the code because i used getrecords() method as well @NiamatullahBakhshi

Comment: oh I see.
can you mail me your project so that I check it without missing anything?

Comment: sure @NiamatullahBakhshi your mail id?

Comment: niamatullahbakhshi@gmail.com

Comment: i will do it tomorrow. @NiamatullahBakhshi

Comment: copy and zip your project and then mail it to me.
would try whatever possible.
**cheers**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @NiamatullahBakhshi please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts/questions.

First to retrieve the data, so that it can be displayed in the editbills activity, you can utilise the row's **id** that is passed to the activity in conjunction with the `getRecordById` method.

I'd suggest that adding a method to the **`editbills`** class will simplyfy matters.

```
    private void populateDisplay(int id) {

        Cursor csr = dbAdapter.getRecordById(id);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            editText.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
            editText2.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT)));
            editText3.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DUEDATE)));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
```

You could invoke the above method after retrieving the **id** from the Intent using :-

```
    populateDisplay(selectedID);
```

---

To update based upon the content's of the EditTexts un-comment the **`updateRecord`** method in **DBAdapter.java** and the change :-

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("test", "adding");
        db.open();
        long id = db.insertRecord(editText.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString());
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(Editbills.this," Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bills.class);
        startActivity(q);

    }
});
```

to :-

```
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dbAdapter.updateRecord(
                    selectedId,
                    editText.getText().toString(),
                    editText2.getText().toString(),
                    editText3.getText().toString())
                    ) {
                Log.d("TEST","Row successfully updated.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Row Updated.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                populateDisplay(selectedId);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Row not Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bills.class);
            startActivity(q);
        }
    });
```

You will additionally have to add a line initialise the `dbAdapter` i.e. `dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);` i.d suggest adding this line immediately after the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_editbills);`

- **Note** the above code is in-principle and has not been thoroughly tested so it may contains errors.

### Edit complete working example :-

The following code is basically an implementation of the above, except modified to utilise a **Bill** class. Rather than an `ArrayList<String>` as the source for the Adapter it has `ArrayList<Bill>`.

Thus all the data (id, name, amount and duedate) is available.

You should notice that I've overridden the `toString` method to return a String that combines the **name**, **amount** and **duedate**. The `ArrayAdapter` uses the object's `toString` method to populate the view.

Saying that the critical value is the **rowid** or an alias of **rowid** as this can be used to identify a row even if the other data is identical *(as would happen when running this example more than once due to the `addSomeData` method)*. Hence, only the **id** is extracted and passed to the Editbills activity when an item in the list is long clicked *(changed from just clicked to reduce the potential for accidental use)*.

### Bill.java

```
public class Bill {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private String duedate;

    public Bill(long id, String name, String amount, String duedate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.duedate = duedate;
    }
    /*
            Note if this Constructor used then setId should be used
     */
    public Bill(String name, String amount, String duedate) {
        new Bill(0,name,amount,duedate);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDuedate() {
        return duedate;
    }

    public void setDuedate(String duedate) {
        this.duedate = duedate;
    }

    /*
            As ArrayAdapter uses toString method change this
            to return all items
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + amount + " " + duedate;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

This is the equivalent to your Bills.java without a lot of the bloat such as FAB. :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ID_INTENTEXTRA = DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID + "_INTENTEXTRA"; //<<<< ADDED

    DBAdapter mDBAdapter;
    Cursor mCsr;
    ListView mrecycleview;
    ArrayAdapter adapter; //<<<< NOT ListAdapter
    Context context; // ADDED
    private static final String TAG ="assignments";

    ArrayList<Bill> mBillList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        mrecycleview = this.findViewById(R.id.mRecycleView);

        mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        addSomeData();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bill>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mBillList
        );
        mrecycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mrecycleview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bill b = (Bill) adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(context,Editbills.class);
                i.putExtra(ID_INTENTEXTRA,b.getId()); //Get ID
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        });
        rebuildBillList();
    }

    //<<<< ADDED Method to refresh the ListView resumed
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        rebuildBillList();
    }

    // Add some data (note will add 2 rows each time it is run)
    private void addSomeData() {
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill1","2018-10-02","English");
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill2","2018-09-03","Mathematics");
        mDBAdapter.insertRecord("Bill3","2018-11-04", "Geography");
    }

    public void rebuildBillList() {
        mBillList.clear();
        mCsr = mDBAdapter.getAllAsCursor();
        while (mCsr.moveToNext()) {
            mBillList.add(new Bill(
                            mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID)),
                            mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME)),
                            mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT)),
                            mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DUEDATE))
                    )
            );
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

- **Note** the above adds 3 rows each time it is run.

### Editbills.java

```
public class Editbills extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    private static final String Tag = "assignments";
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    private String selectedName;
    private long selectedID;
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editbills);
        context = this;
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this); //<<<< ADDED
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        editText3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext3);
        //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

        //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
        selectedID = receivedIntent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.ID_INTENTEXTRA,-1L); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value
        populateDisplay(selectedID);

        //now get the name we passed as an extra
        //selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

        //set the text to show the current selected name
        //editText.setText(selectedName); <<<< commented out
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*
                Log.d("test", "adding");
                db.open();
                long id = db.insertRecord(editText.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString(), editText3.getText().toString());
                db.close();
                Toast.makeText(Editbills.this," Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                */
                /*
                * <<<< Not the way as it ends/closes the existing activity
                Intent q = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(q);
                */
                String toast = "Updated.";
                if (dbAdapter.updateRecord(selectedID,
                        editText.getText().toString(),
                        editText2.getText().toString(),
                        editText3.getText().toString())) {
                } else {
                    toast = "Not Updated.";
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,toast,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish(); //<<<< ends/closes this activity and returns to calling activity
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateDisplay(long id) {
        Cursor csr = dbAdapter.getRecordById(id);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            editText.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
            editText2.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT)));
            editText3.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DUEDATE)));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

- Basically as per the original answer.

### DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "billsdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "bills";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


    // Replaces DATABASE_CREATE using the one source definition
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + // AUTOINCREMENT NOT REQD
                    KEY_NAME + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_AMOUNT + " VARCHAR ," +
                    KEY_DUEDATE + " DATE " +
                    ")";

    private Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE); // NO need to encapsulate in try clause
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts"); //????????
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---opens the database--- NOT NEEDED
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database--- NOT NEEDED
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a record into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String name, String amount, String duedate)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,
                initialValues
        );
    }

    //---deletes a particular record---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the records--- SEE FOLLOWING METHOD
    public Cursor getAllRecords()
    {SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String query ="SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return data;
    }


    //As per getAllRecords but using query convenience method
    public Cursor getAllAsCursor() {
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
                DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
    }
    public Cursor getItemID(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + KEY_ROWID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +
                " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    // Retrieve a row (single) according to id
    public Cursor getRecordById(long id) {
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
                DATABASE_TABLE,
                null,
                KEY_ROWID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                null,null,null
        );
    }

    //---updates a record---
    public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String amount, String duedate) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
        args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
        String whereclause = KEY_ROWID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)};
        return DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(DATABASE_TABLE,
            args,
            whereclause,
            whereargs
        ) > 0;
    }
}
```

- Basically as was except that `upDateRecord` has been un-commented, again as per the original answer.

### Results

#### 1st Run - MainActivity (Bills) :-

[image]

#### Long Click Bill2 (note changed from Click as Long Click is less prone to accidental use)

[image]

#### Change data (Update button not clicked)

[image]

#### Update Button Clicked (Toast was Updated.)

[image]

- Note use of **`finish()`** to return to the invoking activity and then the use of `onResume` to refresh the list according to the updated data *(possibly your next question)*.

  - using `startActivity` will simply result in issues.
- **Note** Values are date and course rather then amount and duedate because I didn't change the values in the `addSomeData` method (easily done).

  - the actual data itself is irrelevant to the process.

Comment: Brother it will not work because see the bills.java, I have already added method that is retrieving name but not others. fields and the update record you suggested is showing "row is not updated"

Comment: Can you please mail the project you have made and thanks for your help again. i will make the amendments to my existing project.  Please do it would be a great help. Shall i provide you the email id?

Comment: The code above, bar the layouts, is all that you need. The layouts are very basic. For the Main Activity you just need a Listview with an id **mRecycleView**. For the Editbills the layout is 3 Edittexts with id's **edittext**, **edittext2** and **edittext3** and a Button with an id of **button**. All id's are name according to those from your code so the existing layouts you have may well be suitable. In fact the whole code is based upon your code.

Comment: Yeah in aaplied the code you suggested. I applied it within 30 minutes when you edited the comment but it was adding 3 items automatically whenever i exit the activity that’s why i was asking for you mail . Thanks anyways it’s a great help. ☺️

Comment: All you have to do is remove the line `addSomeData();` and as it then becomes redunandant delete the `addSomeData` method.

Comment: Okay brother i will try it as well.  Btw thanks brother .  Thanks  for helping so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162920/cannot-convert-java-lang-string-into-json-object @MikeT please help